# Mobilenavi empty - drupal 8

Tags: drupal, responsive, drupal-8

I'm building my first Drupal 8 website and have one issue I hope is related to me working locally (I don't have an online server yet).

My theme is a subtheme of [Nexus](https://www.drupal.org/project/nexus). Everything works fine, except the mobile menu. It remains blank, see screenshot. I have not made any adjustments to it.
[image]

Here's the code from my .info.yml file:

```
<div id="page">
 <header id="masthead" class="site-header container" role="banner">
  <div class="row">
  {% if page.header %}
    <div id="logo" class="site-branding col-sm-6">
      {{ page.header }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
   <div class="col-sm-6 mainmenu">
    <div class="mobilenavi"></div>
    <nav id="navigation" role="navigation">
      <div id="main-menu">
        {% if page.main_navigation %}
            {{ page.main_navigation }}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

As Nexus is Bootstrap based, I could try adding some of Bootstrap navbars code. But I can't figure out where to find page.main_navigation that is being referred to.

Answer (score 0):

nexus i think has a dropdown mobile menu, when you click on the "select a page". it is not your usual "hamburger" menu, also loging off, could declutter the output and make it easy to text

Comment: That's right, but when I click "Select a page" there are no items to select. Though I do have pages listed in my main menu.

Comment: have you tried printing the main nav inside #mobilenavi ?